# Deselect messages easier in the new mobile chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, mobile-web

If you select a message in the new mobile chat the only way to deselect it is to tap the x in the upper left corner.

I think it would make more sense if you could also deselect it by tapping on the message again or tapping on the white space that appears where the text box used to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good idea and works now – if you try to select the message that's already selected, that's as good as clicking the "X" to cancel editing.

The whitespace that appears is really just an artifact that I want to get rid of eventually (it doesn't even happen on Android, because the layout implementation is slightly different), so I haven't bothered making that do the same thing.

Comment: Hmm.. I get the white space on android. Weird.

Comment: Interesting. With what browser?

Comment: Chrome. https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/KhD4r16yw4IWBOr1MFXxxEFVfrxJ6sOi/Screenshot_2016-01-28-15-50-20.png

Comment: Ah okay, yeah, if the chat is scrolled all the way to the bottom, there's nothing there to appear. But as soon as you scroll up, stuff will be there.